# Twillio SMS forwarding Slack bot with webhook

Tags: post, twilio, slack-api, twilio-functions

I have enabled incoming web hooks on Slack API incoming web-hooks. 
Webhook URLs for Your Workspace:

INSTRUCTIONS:

To dispatch messages with your webhook URL, send your message in JSON as the body of an application/json POST request.

Add this webhook to your workspace below to activate this curl example.

Sample curl request to post to a channel:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Hello,     World!"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/T0AFATG95/B73FDS5R6V/hFApP
```

(token is incomplete).

When i send the POST request it works!

APP 2:18 PM
Hello, World!

Now I want to have Twillio send this POST request to slack using a web-hook or TwiML. ???
 This is basically a relay to the slack URL. how do I make a POST request to that URL, so the message sent to the twillio # is sent in the body?

Under twillio phone settings I select what happens when:

A message comes in   Webhook [WEB HOOK GOES HERE]    HTTP POST

OR I CAN USE:

TwiML  Bin instead and assign it in the twilio phone settings.

If I cannot achieve this I will use a lambda function to do it, I just though there might be a way to achieve this since i do not manipulate anything about the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `Twilio Function`, here is the code for the function:

```
const got = require('got');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

  const requestBody = {
    text: event.Body
  };

  got.post('https://hooks.slack.com/services/T0AFATG95/B73FDS5R6V/hFApP', {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
  })
    .then(response => {
      let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
      twiml.message("Your message has been forwarded to Slack.");
      callback(null, twiml);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      callback(err);
    });
};
```

***Notes:***

- `event.Body` holds the SMS message sent to your Twilio number
- if you don't want to send any response to the sender comment out or delete this line: `twiml.message("Your message has been forwarded to Slack.");`
- also read this `Building apps with Twilio Functions` https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007737928-Building-apps-with-Twilio-Functions
- a blog post by @philnash is the inspiration for this answer https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/07/forward-incoming-sms-messages-to-email-with-node-js-sendgrid-and-twilio-functions.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alex! We should add something like this to this repo: https://github.com/philnash/useful-twilio-functions/

Comment: Thank you ALEX!!!!!!!! and Philnash for the inspiration made me look like a superstar at work!!  Usecase: with so many 2 step verification codes in multiple accounts, setting a twilio # in the account phone number allows us to see all the 2 step verification sms codes rather than asking the owner of the Phone number.

Comment: I removed the reply and nothing happens when I trigger the message. Do you know what might cause this ? Normally an Amazon verification code comes in like this FROM: 262-966 625254 is your Amazon security code

Comment: I'm not sure, you might have to upgrade to a paid account.

Comment: Turns out it was the short code, Twilio cannot receive text from short code. I ended up using voice response. your code helped a lot, and I was able to make it server less. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46574133/send-twilio-speech-result-to-working-function