# Send twilio speech result to working function

Tags: javascript, function, twilio

Hello I have the following working function. I am having trouble using the  or  functions properly. Here is the working porting of the code. 
I have tried:

```
  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  twiml.say({ voice: 'man', language: 'en-gb' }, 'Hello I.T.');
```

CODE:

```
const got = require('got');
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
```

I want to record the first 15 seconds of the call and replace "test" with event.SpeechResult.toString()

```
  const requestBody = {
    text: "test"
  };
  got.post('https://hooks.slack.com/services/T08Q2345/B7D6H7U6A/THAVF2343234oSj5x', {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
  })
  .then(response => {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
    callback(null, twiml);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    callback(err);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with 2 functions

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

  twiml.gather({
    input: 'speech',
    timeout: 3,
    action: '/send_slack'
  }).say('HI');
  callback(null, twiml);
};
```

This function records the speech after saying "HI"
Then in the action: it will go to the /send_slack path.
That will trigger the second function : 
make sure the path on the second function is /send_slack or matches the action of the fist.

```
const got = require('got');
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) { 
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  const command = event.SpeechResult.toLowerCase();

  const requestBody = {
    text: command.toString()
  };
  got.post('https://hooks.slack.com/services/T095/B7DA/THAgetyourownSj5x', {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
  })
  .then(response => {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
    callback(null, twiml);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    callback(err);
  });
};
```